# Display series.data.name after drilldown dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to display the series.data.name dynamically after clicking on drilldown

Here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prashu421/5Lzskkwg/4/, now when you click on "Chrome" it drillsdown where I would like to display the text "Chrome", similarly for any other drilldown dynamically, is this possible to do so?

I have found this reference http://jsfiddle.net/KFpJC/2/, but this is using a fixed text to be displayed and hidden.

**Update**: I want the series name to be displayed in the same place where "Plot Band" is displayed in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KFpJC/2/), but after the drilldown only.

```
chart: {
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                drilldown: function () {
                    var myAxis = this.xAxis[0];
                    var myPlotBands = myAxis.plotLinesAndBands;
                    $.each(myPlotBands, function (i, linesAndBands) {
                        linesAndBands.svgElem.hide();
                        if (linesAndBands.label) {
                            linesAndBands.label.css({
                                display: 'none'   
                            });
                        }
                    });
                },
                drillup: function () {
                    $.each(this.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands, function (i, linesAndBands) {
                        linesAndBands.svgElem.show();
                        if (linesAndBands.label) {
                            linesAndBands.label.css({
                                display: 'block'   
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
```

I have newly started working with Highcharts, Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where would you like to display the series name?  In the chart title, as an axis title, in a div somewhere, etc?

Comment: Hello @BarbaraLaird, I would like it to be displayed, in the same place where "Plot Band" is displayed in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/KFpJC/2/ but after drilldown only. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SVGRenderer` in `drilldown` event for this:

```
  drilldown: function(e) {
    this.renderer.text('text', chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth / 2, chart.plotTop + 20).attr({
      zIndex: 3
    }).add();
    (..)
  }
```

---

**Live working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/b3p5yayt/

**API reference:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown